# java sqlite - display select

Tags: java, database, sqlite

These are my tables:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/acdb1

I want to display in Java something like raport:

```
 Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:project.db");
      c.setAutoCommit(false);
      System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

      stmt = c.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT stormtrooper.id, squad.id, platoon.id, company.id, battalion.id FROM stormtrooper\n" +
"INNER JOIN squad ON squad.id=stormtrooper.squad\n" +
"INNER JOIN platoon ON platoon.id=squad.platoon\n" +
"INNER JOIN company ON company.id=platoon.company\n" +
"INNER JOIN battalion ON battalion.id=company.battalion;" );
      String log = "";
      while ( rs.next() ) {
         log+=rs.getInt("id") + " | ";
         log+=rs.getInt("id") + " | ";
         log+=rs.getInt("id") + " | ";
         log+=rs.getInt("id") + " | ";
         log+=rs.getInt("id") + "\n";
      }
      jTextArea1.setText(log);  
         rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      c.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      jTextArea1.setText( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
    }
```

SELECT statement is correct - I checked this. But when I try execute this in Java, I'm getting an error:

```
ambiguous column: 'id'
```

How should it looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of `id` columns in your `SELECT` statement

You have to change the columns names with some like this:

```
SELECT stormtrooper.id AS stormtrooper_id, squad.id AS squad_id, platoon.id AS platoon_id, company.id AS company_id, battalion.id AS battalion_id FROM ...
```